# Achieve a tilt-shiftesque effect in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blur

I'm looking to create an effect similar to the Photoshop "tilt-shift" blur in Illustrator. All the blur effects in Illustrator I could find only blur the whole element, without any "gradient" so to speak. Is it possible to achieve something like this in Illustrator? If so, will the paths of the object still be accessible?

I know I could potentially duplicate the text and put some alphamask gradient on the blurred element, but the effect is not quite the same.

Here's an image example of the effect, which I put together in Photshop. Photoshop requires to rasterize the image. This makes it kind of annoying to work with. Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: All I can think of is an Opacity Mask with a gradient. But you mention that specifically already. So....

Comment: Yeah, this partly works, but unfortunately the blur effect doesn't change in quality, but only in opacity, if you understand what I mean by that.

Comment: Yup. I do. I, myself, don't see the tilt-shift as a possibility in Illustrator. Well, at least not easily. Maybe with multiple masks on multiple objects, etc.

Comment: Yeah I think it'd be easier working with Photoshop for this specific case then (unfortunately). Never thought I'd find something that was NOT possible in Illustrator haha. Alright thank you anyways.

Comment: Maybe a combination of SVG filters could achieve this. I haven't used them in AI so far but I've seen some web examples like https://codepen.io/iamvdo/pen/xECmI

Comment: @aagd Interesting, Ill definitely try this. Going to have to do some research on how to use svg filters in illustrator. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I've been fiddling around with svg effects a little bit, but I don't think your example is possible in Illustrator, as the masking method involves CSS (which I couldn't figure out how to apply to an svg filter in Illustrator). Also, I think this does not change the intensity of the blur, but only the opacity, aswell. Seems weird to me, that there is no real possibility to blur elements like that.

Comment: @Maharkus "Never thought I'd find something that was NOT possible in Illustrator haha." You can do but there is no productivity tool for that now AFAIK. A mere gradient won't help too much here because the un-blurred text will appear too sharp layered with the blurred version. You need to work in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do it to a text (character).

But we can do it after expand the text.

See my methot in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed instructions! I don't think it's neccessary to expand the text, is it? AFAIK blur works on text objects.

Comment: It works in text but not in each character separately inside a word. You have to separate every character.

Answer (score 2):

You need to duplicate the layers and apply different levels of blur to them. Then you mask each layer accordingly.
It is not because there is no easy productivity tools that you can't achieve such a thing. I did not touch Illustrator for about a decade but I believe if Inkscape can afford to do such a thing, Illustrator does too.

Just as the image bellow shows, above a specific work on several layers.
And bellow a gradient between a blurred and an un-blurred text. Which one works best for you?

[image: Gradient Blur with Inkscape]

Comment: I get what you mean, but obviously this is not a too very handy solution to work with. Like changing the text would be really annoying. Still alot better than a Photoshop png! Thank you.

Comment: Well I'm just proposing a solution. The rest is up to you guys. :)
As per changing the text it is a few minutes job.